# Regex - don't match double-quotes unless a specific word appears before

Tags: regex

I'm using the following regex to match any string starting with http:// or https:// and followed by at least one character, disallowing spaces and double quotes.

```
^(http|https):\/\/[^ "]+$
```

What I need to do is allow the double quotes, but only if http:// or https:// is followed by "somethinghere/", eg:

> http://somedomain.com?a="b"

don't match

> http://somethinghere/?a="b"

do match

How should the regex look like to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would follow this approach:

```
/^https?:\/\/(?:somethinghere[^ ]+|[^ "]+)$/
```

basiclly, it allows alternations, with the "special" part being the first (and more exceptions may follow) and the "general" part as last resort.
I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

tried something like `^(http|https):\/\/[\w]+\/(\?[\w]=\"\w+\")*)` .It also allows http://abcd/.If you dont want that replace last `*` with `+`.

You can try all your regex easily [here](http://regexr.com/)